# bash completion for git custom subcommands?

Tags: git, bash-completion, git-completion

Say I have a `git-cc` executable in `PATH`. If `git-cc` supports `--help`, then it is easy to provide adequate completion with

```
complete -F _longopt git-cc
```

This makes `$ git-cc --<TAB>` complete (as per help output). But `git cc --<TAB>` won't complete (even though it runs fine). More importantly if I create a git alias to the custom subcommand, e.g. `cc-sensible-defaults = cc --opt1 ...`, that also won't work, and in this case simply deleting the space (`git-cc` instead of `git cc`) isn't an option.

What to do? I've tried messing around with `__git_complete [git-]cc _longopt`, but none of the various combinations do anything good. It seems to be for completing bash aliases (like `gl = git-log`), not sub-commands. The intro in [git/git-completion.bash](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) is, as expected, not very helpful, containing the confusing

```
# If you have a command that is not part of git, but you would still
# like completion, you can use __git_complete:
#
#   __git_complete gl git_log
#
# Or if it's a main command (i.e. git or gitk):
#
#   __git_complete gk gitk
```

(WTH is _git_log? Did they mean _git_log, which is indeed a function? Is it some convention?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update:

> For me, this solution just makes `<tab>` list all the alternatives every time, no completion, why? I tried `_git_jump() { COMPREPLY=(diff merge grep); }` and `git jump d<tab>` but the output is just listing: `diff   grep   merge` – 
> Moberg

What you have to do, is remove from `COMPREPLY` the words so that only one that starts with `$cur` is left. If you give 3, bash will show you the list. If you reduce `COMPREPLY=(diff)` then it will be auto-completed by Bash.

Taking inspiration of https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L2445 , the following works nicely:

```
_git_jump() { __gitcomp "diff merge grep" "" "$cur"; }
```

Or I think it's better to write similar code yourself, not to depend on `git`:

```
_git_jump() { COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "diff merge grep" -- "${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}") ); }
```

For me https://devmanual.gentoo.org/tasks-reference/completion/index.html is the best introduction how to do it.

---

> What to do?

Just define a function that does the compiletion with leading `_git_` prefix.

```
# you should rather use COMPREPLY+=(..) or call `__gitcomp` to append
$ _git_cc() { COMPREPLY=(-a -b); }
$ git cc <tab>
-a  -b  
$ git cc -
```

See [__git_complete_command](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L3376):

```
__git_complete_command () {
    local command="$1"
    local completion_func="_git_${command//-/_}"
    ...
    if __git_have_func $completion_func
        then
            $completion_func
            return 0
```

> I've tried messing around with __git_complete

As far as I understand the `__git_complete` it's the other way round - you want a normal command complete like git subcommand. For example:

```
$ _git_cc() { COMPREPLY=(-a -b); }
$ alias mycommand='git cc'
$ __git_complete mycommand git_cc                  # or __git_complete mycommand _git_cc
$ mycommand <tab>
-a  -b  
$ mycommand -
```

> WTH is _git_log?

[`_git_log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L2000) is a function the generates completion for `git log`.

> Did they mean _git_log, which is indeed a function?

Yes. See [__git_complete](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash#L3530) tests for existence of a function with `_main` suffix or `_` prefix or without any prefix/suffix.

> Is it some convention?)

Yes.

Comment: Ah good. Do you know how I can reuse _longopt, instead of re-parsing `git-cc --help`, or copying it's current longopts?

Comment: Something along `_git_cc() { _longopt git-cc "${@:2}"; }` may get you started.

Comment: For me, this solution just makes <tab> list *all* the alternatives every time, no completion, why? I tried `_git_jump() { COMPREPLY=(diff merge grep); }` and `git jump d<tab` but the output is just listing: `diff   grep   merge`